Reversing formula
So i have some trouble writing a mapping function. The function should map a normalized value from 0 to 1 to a plain value $p_{min}$ and $p_{max}$ respectively, in a exponential manner. And another function should map a plain value back to a normalized value.
Below is my normalized to plain function.
$$y= p_{min}+((2^{(f*x-f)})-(2^{-f}*(1-x)))*p_{max} $$
So far i have a reverse mapping function, converting a plain value to a normalized value, like this:
$$x=\frac{log_2(\frac{(y-p_{min})}{p_{max}}+2^{-f}+f)}{f}$$
But i noticed this equation is not entirely correct since it does not take the $(1-x)$ into account. Anybody know what the correct  equation would be for converting a plain value to a normalized value?

This is a math site, not a programming site.  It is much clearer to write your question in math format than programming language.  Translating into code is definitely off topic.

I wrote my question in math format now, thanks

Mathematica Solve tells this:
$$x= -\frac{W\left(f \log (2) 2^{\frac{2^f f \left(y-p_{\min }\right)}{p_{\max }}+f}\right)}{f \log (2)}+\frac{2^f \left(y-p_{\min }\right)}{p_{\max }}+1$$
$W(z)$ is the ProductLog function which gives the principal solution for $w$ in $z=w e^w$.
